# Are the expressions "pissed" and "pissed off" inappropriate?

Tags: speech, politeness

I've seen people go quiet when they hear one of them.
I also remember hearing it bleeped on television.
Are they inappropriate?  To what extent?  What audience could or should not hear it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another culture-dependent question.

Both are regarded as profane in the UK; they are commonly used, but generally not in polite company. Whether it would get bleeped on television depends on context, and particularly whether they are before or after the [watershed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(television)).

I get the impression, and it is only an impression *from television*, that both terms are somewhat more acceptable in the US. That is, I've heard them used, particularly *pissed*, in surprisingly polite company.

Note: *Pissed off* is universally understood, but *pissed* has different meanings. In North America, it is synonymous with *pissed off*, but in the UK it means 'inebriated'. Also, we are fond of telling people to 'piss off!' which means something different still...

I remember the end of Monty Python Live at The Hollywood Bowl, after the final encore, 'Piss Off' is used with comedic effect to dismiss the audience. [Script](http://www.intriguing.com/mp/_scripts/livebowl.php)]
[image: Piss Off!]

Comment: Sorry - not the clearest image, but the best I could do.

Comment: @CJM: Whilst we definitely used *pissed* to mean drunk, I have heard plenty of English people use it to mean *"pissed off"* as well.  I would not say either are considered profane at all, certainly not in the younger generations, on a par with *crap* in that regard.

Comment: @Orbling: certainly very true. A couple years ago, I was using *crap* almost every minute. I still use it occasionally. Normally, I don't use *pissed off* or *pissed*, but I hear it in conversation all the time. I mean, I have friends who tell me point blank when "I'm pissing them off"! And I don't bat an eyelid. It may be considered uncouth in certain situations, but among the youth, like you said, the *p* -word is certainly not on the level of the *f* -word, or even the *s* -word, which is gradually being vulgarized (*vulgarize* here means *to make commonplace*).

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I have always thought that the etymology of the word *vulgar* was very apt.  I am not sure citing "the youth of today" on the subject of profanity acceptance was overly wise of me, as a day does not go past without me hearing the c-word *(not crap!)* being thrown about casually in public.

Comment: I’d roughly agree with @Jimi: in my UK experience (I’m in my late twenties), *pissed off* is if anything weaker than *crap* — certainly much weaker than e.g. *shit*.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm approached 40 now, which might define my view on this. *I'm pissed* is **never** used in earshot of me, and that includes amongst my nieces & nephews (16-23yrs) though I can see how it might creep in over time. It's certainly much milder than f & c words, thus I think is often used in comedy, but it's still something you wouldn't say in front of your mum, whereas crap is still technically vulgar, you are unlikely to offend anyone. It is used in work environments, and even my mother-in-law wouldn't object (which is a key barometer!).

Comment: @Orbling: wow at the "c-word". This is my first year in the adult world and I've heard a lot, so far. Certainly not only the "youth of today"! @CJM: I agree it's probably "something you wouldn't say in front of your mum". Probably not also in front of your professor or superior in some other setting. I should also add that I'm 23 and currently in northeastern part of the US; I guess a lot does depend on where you live. Certainly agree that *pissed off* is not something you'd consider offensive on TV, for sure.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: There are regional differences in the degree of offensiveness of words, and even more so between classes.  The UK populous seem to swear a lot it seems to me, much more in reality than TV - I can not say for the States, as I mainly have only TV to go on and the rules are stricter there.

Comment: As the saying goes, it is "... better to be pissed off than pissed on."  It occurs to me that, paradoxically,  "pissed off" seems somehow LESS offensive than "pissed on.". Possibly because the latter refers more directly to the act of urinating?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your audience. They wouldn't be appropriate for an audience of children (say, Sesame Street), but probably ok for a late night comedy show (say, Adult Swim or stand up). For a work setting, I would avoid using them except when you really need to express anger and vitriol, and even then there are more appropriate ways to say it.

And of course, among your friends you should often try to say things that piss them off :)

Answer (score 1):

I consider it a swear word. It is not something I was allowed to say growing up, and it is not something I let my kids say. All of the terms come from a rude word for urination similar to the 's' word for defecation. No one I know from kids to teens to adults says this word in polite company (at work or at church or in public). I am in the midwest US.

Answer (score 0):

My daughter is writing a novel for school, and she used the word "pissed". I have no idea if it is appropriate for her school, but I think it is fine. It just means that someone is extremely angry.